# Image is not appearing on Android Lollipop

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview, android-5.0-lollipop, android-image

I am trying to pick an image from the gallery on Android Lollipop and show it on the display. I am using following code to go to the gallery and pick the image:

```
Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(
                Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
// Start the Intent
startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, RESULT_LOAD_IMG);
```

I am using following code to pick the image and display it:

```
Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

// Get the cursor
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
        filePathColumn, null, null, null);
// Move to first row
cursor.moveToFirst();

int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
imgDecodableString = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
cursor.close();

// Set the Image in ImageView after decoding the String
ImageViewFinal.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory
        .decodeFile(imgDecodableString));
```

Somehow the selected image is not being displayed. It works fine on lower Android versions but is not working on Lollipop. Logcat is also not showing any error, that means image is actually getting selected but for some reason it is hiding behind grey screen.

Comment: Can you post two Uris you get from `data.getData()`; one when it loads correctly and otherwise.

Comment: Thanks for prompt response Janitha. selectedImage this is uri and it is working fine in KitKat but not working in lollipop.

Comment: You were asked to tell the values of uri.getPath().

Comment: Is cursor null? Check for null and do not continue if it is. Then after that what is the value of imgDecodableString ? Does the code flow to there or do you have a catch somewhere? Finally you should check the return value of decodeFile(). It will be null.

Comment: @JanithaR @greenapps I have stored this file in uri `File mediaStorageDir = new File(
    Environment
      .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
    IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME);`

Stored file in uri, `Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile(type));`

And here is the value,

    `final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileUri.getPath(),
     options);
`

Comment: @greenapps No curser is not null. It is getting stored in `ImageView` in KitKet but is not getting stored in Lollipop. `imgDecodableString = cursor.getString(columnIndex);

ImageViewFinal.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory
     .decodeFile(imgDecodableString));`

Comment: ???? You are not telling values. You only repeat your code. You dont have to repeat your code as we already know your code. Now you should tell the values.

Comment: @greenapps I did not use `uri.getPath()`. I directly use `data.getData();` method for selecting uri.

Comment: My god, i asked the value of selectedImage.getPath() of course.

Comment: @greenapps I understood what you are trying to convey but I did not use `selectedImage.getPath()` anywhere in my code. I have used it to get the image from camera but not to get image from gallery. Using above code I have posted in my question, I successfully get the image from gallery to display in KitKet, but not in Lollipop.

Comment: Do not repeat yourself. Even if you do not use it yourself... i'm asking for it... for a reason... now if you want help...

Comment: @greenapps okay. I took this file. `File mediaStorageDir = new File(
    Environment
      .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
    IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME);` and used this file here. `public Uri getOutputMediaFileUri(int type) {
  return Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile(type));
 }` and used uri in bitmap`final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileUri.getPath(),
     options);` and then that bitmap stored in imageView. `ImageViewFinal.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
`

Comment: Sorry, but what is wrong with you? For the third time you posted code. I know your code already so reposting does not make sense. I asked for values. You did not show any value.

Comment: try using picasso library for image loading it's super easy

Comment: Try replacing ImageViewFinal with imageViewFinal

Comment: @greenapps I really appreciate you are trying to help me but there is no value in my current code so how can I tell you.

Comment: @user912010 Let me try it out. Thanks for the response

Comment: @HusseinElFeky thanks buddy. Let me try if it works

Comment: Are you a programmer? If you define a Sring variable mywords like 'String mywords ="there is no value"; then the value of variable mywords is "there is no value"; Now please mention all the values i asked for.

Comment: @greenapps  I took only one String directly in above code and defined uri.  I did not define any other string in my code anywhere.

Comment: You do not have to declare a variable to know or tell the value. Well last try: selectedImage.getPath() returns a String. What is the value of the returned String?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that worked for me. Here it is,

```
Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
    String[] projection = { MediaColumns.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(selectedImageUri, projection, null, null,
            null);
    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaColumns.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();

    String selectedImagePath = cursor.getString(column_index);

    Bitmap bm;
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selectedImagePath, options);
    final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 200;
    int scale = 1;
    while (options.outWidth / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE
            && options.outHeight / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE)
        scale *= 2;
    options.inSampleSize = scale;
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selectedImagePath, options);

    ImageViewFinal.setImageBitmap(bm);
```

I thank you so much all for showing your interest to help me with this.

Comment: You forgot to tell what the problem really was. And why you adapted the code in this way.

Comment: @greenapps my previous code was not working in lollipop so I tried above code and it worked in all android versions.

Comment: My god. It did not work. But why didn't it work? What was the reason? You should tell why it did not work. And how you solved it.

Comment: @greenapps previous code was not showing any error even in logcat when I run it so I did not know the reason. App was running successfully but image was hiding behind grey screen. So selected image was actually there on display but as hidden. I searched for this in Google and today I found a new piece of code in Google android developer group. This was updated code that successfully runs in all android version for getting image from Gallery to display. previous code was running only upto KitKat version.

Comment: Unbelievable that you cannot tell why the old code did not work and the new code does. Unbelievable.